# why does an application hangs itself when there are many requests?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I do not understand why application goes down when there are too many requests? How can I test my application for its maximum capacity to respond to a requests?

Comment: Check what what happened in tomcat/logs directory and post here,  im sure catalina.out has something to say

Comment: You should ask yourself what you expect the application to do instead?

Comment: Time for you to read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why application goes down when there are too many requests?

If you are asking about a specific application, the answer is the we don't know either, and we don't have any evidence from which we could deduce what the problem might be.  Places to look for evidence:

- Check server the logs.
- If you have a reverse proxy, check the proxy's logs.
- Check the backend database logs.
- Check the system-level performance stats; e.g. look for evidence of VM thrashing, disc I/O overload and so on.
- Check for pathological GC behavior.
- Check for blocked / jammed threads, indicating concurrency bottlenecks, deadlocks and so on.

If you are asking in the general case, there can be any number of causes:

- Running out of an external resource (e.g. database connections)
- Creating too many threads
- Trying to queue every request to avoid dropping requests, and other broken strategies.
- Concurrency bottlenecks
- Pathological algorithm or database query design that results in performance that decays under load.
- Broken error recovery; e.g. underload you start getting unexpected exceptions, and this triggers resource leaks.
- And so on ...

> and how to test my application for its maximum capacity to respond to requests ...

Create a test harness to repeatedly send requests to your server and see what rate the server can sustain.  There are existing freameworks for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think application is hanged? May be it just doing some long-running operation?

"Hanging down on too many requests" sounds like either you ran out of resources (e.g., DB connections), though, you should see some exception stack trace somewhere in logs on this case, or you have some concurrency problem.

To know for sure, you need to make thread dump and see if all threads are doing what you expect them to do. You can pay attention to threads of your application only at the start (database threads, logic and servlet threads), as it somewhat unlikely that Tomcat or SQL server has some bug inside them. Try to find place where your application stop behaving as you  expect it to, by looking into logs (or adding them, if needed).